# How to minimize limitation/pain from blisters caused before a camping trip?

Tags: camping, first-aid, blisters

I have a short camping trip coming up. This week, from using a wooden tool, I got blisters on my hands at the base of some fingers. In the future, ideally, I would take precaution to *not* get blisters before a camping trip. Alas, I have them, now what can I do? During the trip I expect to cut wood with axe & saw, keep a fire, and work with ropes setting up, moving around, and breaking down camp.

I'm not worried about this trip as it's so short and the blisters aren't that bad to begin with. It does make me wonder though, if I have blisters and know I'll be potentially making them much worse, what are the best things I can do in between to heal and prep these spots for more friction? Wearing light work gloves in the first place or at camp is an obvious answer but are there other methods to treat the blisters directly?

---

As for related questions:

This addresses the first-aid options pretty well. [Should you pop a blister?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/756/should-you-pop-a-blister) If anything it makes me think, pop and treat these blisters while I can and then wrap them before expecting to apply more friction?

This explains how to use wraps to protect the blister in the field. [How to apply duct tapes and mole skin to prevent blisters?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4346/how-to-apply-duct-tapes-and-mole-skin-to-prevent-blisters) Given the blisters are on my hand in this case, work gloves would suffice.

Comment: I think your related question answers this pretty well. [The answer to "should I deflate this blister" comes down to a very simple question: Will it pop itself if I don't?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/756/should-you-pop-a-blister). If your expecting that your blister is going to pop on your trip then sort it before it does this otherwise wait.

Comment: If this isn't a dupe I think you need to clarify what information that's not in that question your missing. As it stands all your information appears to be there?

Comment: Yea I think nhinkle's answer in https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/756/should-you-pop-a-blister does answer this question I had actually. Sorry about that!